# Can I Use My Sanitizers(PBW, Starsan) For Personal Hygiene?-CORONAVIRUS RELATED

Tags: sanitation, sanitizer, starsan, safety, pbw

As the coronavirus keeps spreading, I was wondering if we can use the sanitizers that we use in brewing for personal hygiene? I'm having difficulties finding sanitizers as everything is sold out here. Have any of you tested this?

Comment: This would still be effective on surfaces in place of bleach right?

Comment: Yes, it should still be effective on surfaces

Answer (score 6):

No. Use soap and water. Wash your hands for 20-30 seconds and make sure you wash your whole hand.

I have no idea what dilution you would have to use to maintain efficacy or what dilution you would have to be below to not give yourself chemical burns.

[image: How to wash hands WHO guidance]

Answer (score 4):

No. Not because they might not be effective, but because they are not made with your skin in mind. Their pH values, either acid or alkaline, are not compatible with your skin, and products for personal hygiene will also contain product to care for your skin, even alcoholic hand sanitiser.

Use a real soap and scrub well.